# gitignore include a specific path

Tags: gitignore

In my .gitignore I have the line:

```
/storage/*.key
```

But I don't want to ignore this specific path and all it's content:

```
/storage/app/public/*
```

Now, inside that path there's another .gitinore file and it has:

```
*
!.gitignore
```

And in the same path there's another .gitignore with:

```
*
!public/
!.gitignore
```

I thought that would be for add the path but is not working.

What is that? How can do what I want (add the path of storage/app/public*)?

Answer (score 0):

Simply check which exact .gitignore and which exact rule is ignoring public:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
# from the root folder of the repo:
git check-ignore -v /storage/app/public/aFileWithinPublic
```

You need to test a file, since a folder is not tracked by Git.

The rule is simple:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**

So if the folder public is ignored (by a '*' rule in a parent .gitignore) of if any of the parent folder of public is ignored, no amount of exclusion will be able to make public content not-ignored.

So this is good (from the `.gitignore` in `storage/app/`, parent of `public/` folder):

```
*
!public/
```

But if `storage/app/` or `storage/` are ignored themselves, this exclusion would be ignored as well.

That is why `git check-ignore -v /storage/app/public/aFileWithinPublic` is important: it will explain what causes the folder content to *still* be ignored.